# SQL Server Engine optimization in Views

Tags: sql-server

I've two DataBases *DB1* and *DB2* in the same SQL Server instance. Here's the structure of both DBs

**DB1**

TableA:

```
[key]      Id   int  
[required] Name nvarchar(50)
```

**DB2**

TableB:

```
[key]      Id           int
[required] Total        real
[required] IdTableA     int  // Foreign key
```

In DB1 I also have a view:

TableBView:

```
select * from DB2.dbo.TableB
```

Now I run the following query

```
select Total
from DB1.TableBView
where Total > 100
```

I wanna know whether the SQL Engine:

1. **a)** is running first the query defined by the view (which return all rows and all columns) **b)** and then select the rows *where Total > 100* or
2. it's applying the *where* statement directly to the View's query and it's only returning the column *Total* from the View's query?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/439061/3915817 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1867979/3915817

Comment: @KHeaney thanks for the links! They are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

So when you run a `VIEW` the optimizer goes to the `VIEW` definition and grabs that `QUERY PLAN`. It then executes that `QUERY PLAN`, then it executes your `WHERE` clause. So to answer question all rows will be selected then your filter will be applied. Now all this can change depending on if you `materialized` your view (put an index on it) then, all rows wouldn't be returned. The query would be filtered and then only rows total > 100 would be processed.